# Why/when can the chemical structure of crystals be assumed to be diffraction gratings?

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

Why/when can the chemical structure of crystals be assumed to be diffraction gratings?

Like how does one know a priori, whether the structure is like a diffraction grating, if one doesn't yet know the structure?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating#Natural_gratings

Comment: First rule of solid state physics: Just shoot it with a laser. Does it produce a diffraction pattern? Then it acts like a diffraction grating. No structure information needed ;)

Comment: Crystals have a spatially repeating structure so by definition will diffract. Not sure quite what the question here is.

Comment: @JonCuster The Wikipedia perhaps explains is lousily, because it seems to say that one can assume that crystals act as diffraction gratings, even if one doesn't know that they do. That the mere property of "being a crystal" is enough. Even though it sounds more reasonable that a material must be also identified as a crystal first (and how is that done without diffraction pattern?).

Answer (score 1):

Always. Crystals have a spatially repeating structure. Each atom scatters light in all directions. For two atoms near each other, light in some directions are in phase, and reinforce. Because the crystal is periodic, there are many other pairs just like this one. They all reinforce light in those same directions.

Atoms are small. They only scatter light where the wavelength is not much larger than an atom. Visible light is much too long. X-rays are used.

The value of the diffraction pattern is that one can work backwards from it to figure out the crystal structure.

Comment: Is the "have a spatially repeating structure" found out by shooting it and then seeing that it produces a certain diffraction pattern? Or in some other way? So is diffraction pattern also a way (the only way?) to identify crystals?

Comment: X-ray diffaction is one way to identify an unknown crystal. But the properties of crystals is a broad topic in solid state physics. Depending on the situation, other properties can be used. There is no single answer. For example, the repeating structure causes many crystals to grow in regular shapes. Crystals in rocks can often be identified by shape and color.